# Is there a way for the handler inside .then() method to access the newly created Promise object?

Tags: es6-promise

I have a chaining promise like this:

```
doSomething1().then(doSomething2).then(doSomething3) ...
```

Now I'd like to put a marker on each Promise object returned by `.then()` method for later code analysis. `doSomething` as an anonymous function, whose context is by default the `window` object. Is there a way to set the handler's context `this` pointing to the newly created Promise object?

Also, is there a way to list all the immediate `then()` attached to a particular `Promise` object?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Your question isn't quite clear

Comment: @ParijatPurohit sure. I'd love to make it clearer. But it's just a concept in my head. Which part would you suggest to add more details? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314, as I put in my question body, I want to put some logging inside the `.then()`, to mark that particular `Promise` object. Something like: `this.marker = "I'm the first step Promise!"; console.log(this.marker);` But apparent `this` does not point to the `Promise` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the functions to be called withing an object and use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as executor passed to `Promise` constructor to preserve `this` referencing the context of the object where function is defined.

```js
let promises = {
  marker: "I'm before the first step Promise!",
  doSomething1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.marker = "I'm the first step Promise!";
        console.log(this.marker);
        resolve(this);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 900))
    })
  },
  doSomething2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.marker = "I'm the second step Promise!";
        console.log(this.marker);
        resolve(this);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200))
    })
  },
  doSomething3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.marker = "I'm the third step Promise!";
        console.log(this.marker);
        resolve(this);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500))
    })
  }
}

console.log(promises.marker);

promises.doSomething1()
.then(promises.doSomething2)
.then(promises.doSomething3)
```

Comment: Arrow functions do not have context `this`. Sorry.